# How do I check if a chrome extension is installed?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I have an angular 4 app and I would like to check if a Chrome Extension is installed, if not, I would like to show a button to install it.

I have tried to find a package to do it but cannot find anything. Anyone have sugestions to do that?

I can edit both the angular app, and the chrome extension.

Thanks.

Comment: You control this extension? Can you have it inject something into the page you can look for?

Comment: Yes, I do control this extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a content script for your own extension that only fires on your website and, say, injects a flag in the DOM that you can check for. For example (this code is untested; it's just meant to illustrate the principle):

**myExtensionDetector.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.__EXTENSION_IS_INSTALLED__ = true;
}
```

Then, in your manifest:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  ...
  content_scripts: [
    ...
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": "https://mywebsite.com",
      "js": ["myExtensionDetector.js"]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Finally, in your website code:

```
function isExtensionInstalled() {
  return window.__EXTENSION_IS_INSTALLED__ !== undefined;
}
```

So, if the extension is installed, that content script will be injected on page load, and the flag will be set in the page. Otherwise, the flag will be undefined. So you can use the existence of the flag as an indicator of whether or not the extension is installed.